# kivy widgets doesn't appear just show black screen

Tags: python, kivy, widget

I am a new learner of the Kivy module.I am practicing making a selfie app by following a video, by clicking on the button, the camera takes a frame and export it as a PNG image. in code I am adding widget (camera, button), and what show is a black screen. so what should I do?

```
import cv2
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class selfie_app(App):
    def make(self):
        self.obj_camera = Camera()
        self.obj_camera.resolution = (810, 810)
        obj_button = Button(text="Click !!")
        obj_button.size_hint = (.5,.2)
        obj_button.pos_hint = {'x':.15, 'y':.15}
        obj_button.bind(on_press = self.selfie_take())
        obj_layout = BoxLayout()
        obj_layout.add_widget(obj_button)
        obj_layout.add_widget(self.obj_camera)
        return obj_layout

    def selfie_take(self, *args):
        print("selfie taken successfully !")
        self.obj_camera.export_to_png('./demo_file.png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    selfie_app().run()
```

Comment: Change `make(self)` to `build(self)`.

Comment: `bind` needs function's name without `()` and when you press button then it will use `()` to run this function - `bind(on_press=self.selfie_take)`