# I am designing a selfie app using kivy module in python, But while executing in PyCharm it is showing blank interface as output

Tags: python, kivy

Here is the code that which I am working on
while executing the below code it is showing blank interface in pycharm

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Selfie_app(App):
    def make(self):
        self.obj_camera = Camera()
        self.obj_camera.resolution = (320,320)
        obj_button = Button(text = 'click')
        obj_button.size_hint(.6, .3)
        obj_button.pos_hint = {'x':35, 'y':35}
        obj_button.bind(on_press = self.selfie_take())
        obj_layout = BoxLayout()
        obj_layout.add_widget(self.obj_camera)
        obj_layout.add_widget(obj_button)
        return obj_layout
    def selfie_take(self,*args):
        print('Selfie has taken sucessfully')
        self.obj_camera.export_to_png('My image')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Selfie_app().run()
```

Comment: One mistake is your `bind` should be like this `obj_button.bind(on_press = self.selfie_take)`

Comment: There are several issues with your code, like in `make` ( should be [**`build`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.build) ) [**`pos_hint`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint), [**`size_hint`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size_hint) etc.

Comment: Check the comments on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72808858/kivy-widgets-doesnt-appear-just-show-black-screen#comment128602415_72808858).